# Are `x = &v` and `*x = v` equivalent?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int * x;
int v = 7;
```

Given this code, what is the difference between 
1. `x = &v` , and 
2. `*x = v` ? 
I understand that in both cases, `*x` contains `7` but does `x` contain memory location of `v` in both cases? If not, what does `x` contain in cases 1 and 2, and is this the only significant difference between the two?

Comment: `*x=v` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: "I understand that in both cases, *x contains 7" - No. Your understanding is wrong. Your second example is [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) - aka invalid/broken/bad code.

Comment: Did you mean executing *both* statements, i.e. `x = &v` followed by `*x = v`? That would have different results than just executing one or the other.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Given the statement:

```
int v = 7;
```

`v` has some location in memory. Doing:

```
x = &v;
```

will "point" `x` to the memory location of `v`, and indeed `*x` will have the value `7`.

However, in this statement:

```
*x = v;
```

you are storing the value of `v` at the address pointed at by `x`. But `x` is *not* pointing at a valid memory address, and so this statement invokes undefined behavior.

So to answer your question, *no*, the 2 statements are not equivalent.

Comment: Specifically, `*x = v` will usually result in writing the number 7 to a random byte in memory. If you're lucky, the program will crash. If you're unlucky, there's just a random 7 in your process' memory. If you're _really_ unlucky you'll write 7 to memory owned by something else, [causing the printer to destroy itself](https://nwn.blogs.com/nwn/2018/06/windows-second-life-yoz-linden-lab.html).

Answer (score 14):

`x = &v` modifies x. After the operation x will point to v.

`*x = v` modifies the object pointed by x. In the example, x doesn't point at anything because the pointer is uninitialised. As such, the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 6):

`&` means address of.

`*` means value at.

In `x = &v` the address of `v` is assigned to `x`.

In `*x = v` - the value at `x` (the value at the address `x`) is assigned the value `v`.

Answer (score 5):

These two are very different statements.

Initially `x` will contain garbage value. Therefore `*x` will try to dereference an uninitialised address and will result in an undefined behaviour (in most of the cases a segmentation fault) as `*x` refers to something which is not initialised. Therefore, `*x = v` assigns the value in `v` to the location which is pointed by `x`.

In the `x = &v`, `x` will contain the address of `v`. From this point `x` contains the address of `v`, `*x` will refer to the value in `v`. Therefore this statement is correct. Therefore, `x = &v` assigns the address of `v` as the value of `x`.

Answer (score 3):

The first assigns a value to `x`. The second has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`int v=7;`

Let's say the address of v = 00ZXCDFCDGDD2345

`int x=&v;`

Here '&' means the address of and **x** is used to store the address *`*(00ZXCDFCDGDD2345)*`*, and x itself stored at some location say *`*00254DBHJBDHDW*`*.

Now if we want to access the value of v we use the pointer.

`int *x=v;`

In this statement '*x' is a pointer variable which points to **v**, means it stores the value of v but the x itself is undefined, it stores the garbage value. 
Hence both are different.